# Thonny creates an error installing ts2vg, yet installs other packages fine

Tags: python, package, thonny

I tried running some code I wrote a month or so ago on my Mac. It runs fine until it gets to the functions required from ts2vg. When I run the code, it gives an error that ts2vg isn't found, thus I went to install it. However the package manager in Thonny won;t install it and gives an error.

I wondered if it was my Mac, so I tried installing a different package and that works fine.

I have tried installing through Thonny, however that didn't work. I also tried through the command line using pip but the same error occured. I am hoping someone can help fix this, as I need ts2vg to run the code! Many thanks in advance.

install --user --upgrade ts2vg==1.2.1

Collecting ts2vg==1.2.1

Downloading ts2vg-1.2.1.tar.gz (643 kB)

```
 ━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━━ 644.0/644.0 kB 6.5 MB/s eta 0:00:00
```

Installing build dependencies: started

Installing build dependencies: finished with status 'done'

Getting requirements to build wheel: started

Getting requirements to build wheel: finished with status 'error'

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.

│ exit code: 1

╰─> [22 lines of output]

```
  Traceback (most recent call last): 

    File "/Applications/Thonny.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 351, in <module> 

      main() 

    File "/Applications/Thonny.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 333, in main 

      json_out['return_val'] = hook(**hook_input['kwargs']) 

    File "/Applications/Thonny.app/Contents/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib/python3.10/site-packages/pip/_vendor/pep517/in_process/_in_process.py", line 118, in get_requires_for_build_wheel 

      return hook(config_settings) 

    File "/private/var/folders/xt/fhwfvllj4wsf3qn2dhd1nz7c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zg8vg71q/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 341, in get_requires_for_build_wheel 

      return self._get_build_requires(config_settings, requirements=['wheel']) 

    File "/private/var/folders/xt/fhwfvllj4wsf3qn2dhd1nz7c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zg8vg71q/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 323, in _get_build_requires 

      self.run_setup() 

    File "/private/var/folders/xt/fhwfvllj4wsf3qn2dhd1nz7c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zg8vg71q/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/setuptools/build_meta.py", line 338, in run_setup 

      exec(code, locals()) 

    File "<string>", line 49, in <module> 

    File "<string>", line 43, in main 

    File "/private/var/folders/xt/fhwfvllj4wsf3qn2dhd1nz7c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zg8vg71q/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 973, in cythonize 

      module_list, module_metadata = create_extension_list( 

    File "/private/var/folders/xt/fhwfvllj4wsf3qn2dhd1nz7c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zg8vg71q/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 816, in create_extension_list 

      for file in nonempty(sorted(extended_iglob(filepattern)), "'%s' doesn't match any files" % filepattern): 

    File "/private/var/folders/xt/fhwfvllj4wsf3qn2dhd1nz7c0000gn/T/pip-build-env-zg8vg71q/overlay/lib/python3.10/site-packages/Cython/Build/Dependencies.py", line 114, in nonempty 

      raise ValueError(error_msg) 

  ValueError: 'ts2vg/utils/pairqueue.pyx' doesn't match any files 

  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Getting requirements to build wheel did not run successfully.

│ exit code: 1

╰─> See above for output.

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Process returned with code 1

Comment: What version of MacOS are you using?

Comment: Hi Carlos, I am using Ventura 13.2.1.